# calling the jq function like you would do a js function from a form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, forms, call

i am trying to validate a form using jquery (not use the validate plugin)...what i wanted to know was is there a way to call the same function without it being attached to a particular node...

like in js

```
<input id="xyz" ....onblur=js:function()>

<input id="abc" ....onblur=js:function()>
```

where as in jq

```
$(#xyz).blur(); 
$(#abc).blur();
```

not the exact syntax but you do get it...

thanks
andy

Comment: You want to invoke an inline handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $(":input").blur(function() { 
    // executes this function every time the blur event
    // fires on any input element
  });
}
```

"input element" being input, textarea, select and button elements.

If you just want it to be executed when the blur event fires for regular inputs, lose the colon.
Hope I got what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I *hope* I'm understanding this right.  To attach those event handlers unobtrusively, use a `document.ready` handler, and add them inside, like this:

```
$(function() { //runs when the DOM is ready
  $("#xyz").blur(function() {
    //do some validation...
  }); 
  $("#abc").blur(function() {
    //do some validation...
  }); 
});
```

Then your handlers need no inline functions, they can just be:

```
<input id="xyz" name="xyz" type="text">
<input id="abc" name="abc" type="text">
```

Comment: not exactly....what i want to do is call $(function() every time there is a blur event(as in everytime i  enter or delete stuff from input on the form)...

Comment: so what you are saying is that every time I enter or edit stuff on the event form the jquery will be called without me having to call it...?

Comment: @andy - that's what this will do, the code inside the handlers above will be executed whenever a `blur` happens. Test it out here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xQak4/ @alex - thanks!

Comment: /@alex - just one last question if i entered data in xyz will abc also be checked ???

Comment: @andy - this checks them independently, do you want to check every input with the same validation handler?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#xyz, #abc').blur(function() {
    //Wrap into jQuery object
    var $this = $(this);

    //console.log($this);

    //Do some validations
    $this.val($.trim($this.val()));
    if(!$this.val().length) {
        alert('box is empty');
    }
});
```